# How to detect if a browser player can handle a video format

Tags: javascript, firefox, html5-video, mp4

I'm trying to play .mp4 video in browsers using their HTML5 player.

However, Firefox doesn't handle the .mp4 video format. So in this case I want to switch to a Flash player that can do the job.

Instead of using the following JavaScript code, which is known as unreliable:

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->

if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('firefox') > -1)
{
     //Do Firefox-related activities
}
```

Is there a way to identify the HTML5 player and to know if it can handle a .mp4 video format?

Comment: I couldn't find a method that returns playable formats. But this link might help you provide a better fallback (check under fallback options): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video

Comment: Awesome man, that did it, I'll post the solution!

Answer (score 4):

You can do that just with HTML5 providing several formats and/or alternatives. Each browser will choose the one that fits better:

```
<video width="1280" height="720" controls="controls">
   <source src="video/movie.ogg" type="video/ogg" />
   <source src="video/movie.webm" type="video/webm" />
   <source src="video/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
   <!-- none of the formats supported -> provide flash -->
   <!-- YOUR EMBED FLASH PLAYER --> 
</video>
```

Sure, this should work. I used a Youtube Flash version. You only have to set your own Flash Object version:

```
<video width="1280" height="720" controls="controls">
   <source src="video/movie.ogg" type="video/ogg" />
   <source src="video/movie.webm" type="video/webm" />
   <source src="video/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
   <!-- none of the formats supported -> provide flash -->
   <object width="420" height="315">
       <param name="movie" value="//www.youtube.com/v/z82D_dBAA8Y?hl=es_ES&amp;version=3"></param>
       <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param>
       <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param>
       <embed src="//www.youtube.com/v/z82D_dBAA8Y?hl=es_ES&amp;version=3" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="420" height="315" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true"></embed>
   </object>
</video>
```

Comment: But I don't want to have many versions of the same video in different formats on the servers. However your example say that if none of the format are supported then an embedded flash player can be used.
I tried [this](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/simple-html5-video-flash-fallback-custom-controls/) but couldn't get it to work.
Could you provide an example ?

Comment: I just tried it but i can't get it to work on mozilla.
here is a codepen http://codepen.io/Micka33/pen/zypnf.
can you tell me what is wrong ?

Answer (score 3):

Thanks @Skymt.

> I couldn't find a method that returns playable formats. But this link
>   might help you provide a better fallback (check under fallback
>   options):
>   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video#Showing_fallback_content_when_no_source_could_be_decoded

---

I'm using [videojs](http://www.videojs.com/) here is my javascript code:

```js
videojs("videoViewer", {playerFallbackOrder: ["html5", "flash", "links"]}, function(){});
var v = document.querySelector('video');
source = v.querySelector('source');
source.addEventListener('error', function(ev)
{
    videojs("videoViewer", {playerFallbackOrder: ["flash", "html5", "links"]}, function(){});
}, false);
```

It is very similar to the exemple you'll find on the link, the only difference is that I only have 1 source, and I am using [videojs](http://www.videojs.com/).

### **So what is happening when I try to play a .mp4 in firefox ?**

1. I instantiate the html5 video player provided by [videojs](http://www.videojs.com/)
2. The html5 video player will display an error saying it can't read this video format and fire an error event
3. The code above will catch the error event
4. I then use [videojs](http://www.videojs.com/) changing its fallback order option, to instantiate a flash player.

### **Does it work only in firefox ?**

No, this will work in all browsers, even those which do not have a html5 video player since [videojs](http://www.videojs.com/) will automatically fallback on the flash version.

### **Does it work only with mp4 ?**

No, this will work whenever an error is fired by the html5 video player, no matter the video format.